# Weak topology coarser than norm topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis

In these lecture notes [on page 71](https://www.math.tu-berlin.de/fileadmin/i26_fg-kutyniok/Fritz/FA2_WS1415/FAII.pdf)(Example 5.29 a) it is claimed that for a LCS X the weak topology is coarser than the topology of the LCS, but afaik this does not even hold for normed spaces or am I wrong?

I mean it would imply that any weakly open neighborhood is open in the LCS topology or am I wrong?

But any weakly open neighborhood of zero contains a whole non-trivial subspace and this is definitely not the case, if $X$ is a normed space, so there are open sets that are not open in the norm topology! Or where is my argument wrong?

Comment: I disagree with your last remark ( in round brackets). The open strip $\{\lvert x\rvert<1\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is an open neighborhood of the origin and it contains the vector subspace $\{x=0\}$.

Comment: sorry, my question went somewhat in the wrong direction the way I asked it. I edited it

Comment: *Coarser* means *has fewer open sets*.

Comment: yes, but doesn't it mean that every weakly open set would be open in the norm topology too and I think that this is false.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point about the weakly open neighborhood of zero. If you have a weakly open neighborhood of zero, then yes, it contains a nontrivial subspace. But this set is is also open in the norm topology. But this does not imply that any strongly open neighborhood of zero contains a nontrivial subspace. In fact one would expect the opposite, if the weak topology is strictly coarser than the strong one.

Comment: @Ian how could I show then that any weakly open set is also open in the LCS topology?- this is basically my question.

Comment: @David13 Before continuing: you should think about quantifiers here. *Each* weakly open set is strongly open, while *some* strongly open sets are not weakly open. This means that universal statements can be transferred from strong to weak (for example, strongly convergent sequences are weakly convergent). On the flipside, existential statements can be transferred from weak to strong.

Comment: @David13 As for your question, the weak topology is the coarsest topology such that a given family of functions (into a fixed topological space) are all continuous. So you need to check that the functions in question are strongly continuous in your setting. Usually this is trivial (for example, the weak topology on a normed space makes the bounded linear functionals continuous, and they're obviously strongly continuous).

Comment: @Ian thanks, now I have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ be two topologies on a given set $X$. We say that $\tau_1$ is *coarser* than $\tau_2$ if $\tau_1\subseteq \tau_2$. This means that if $U$ is open with respect to $\tau_1$ then it is open with respect to $\tau_2$. The converse need not be true.

Now, given a locally convex space $X$, $\tau_1$ being the weak topology is coarser than $\tau_2$, the original topology of $X$.

Note that the inclusion in general need not be strict. Indeed, the weak topology of a weak topology of a Banach space is the same as the weak topology of a Banach space itself.